# Private Node drops transactions while solana-test-validator does not

Tags: solana-test-validator, local-cluster, private-node

I am trying to run a custom benchmark for Solana and have noticed the following odd (or maybe not) behaviour.

I create a single node cluster by following the instructions in: https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-start. Then, I deploy a program and start sending random transactions to it at a rate that I provide as an argument to my benchmark. I want to send a total of 10000txs at a rate of 160 tps which seems not to be very large.

**Problem**: After some time, I check the logs and the node starts retrying transactions and eventually drops them after they expire.

[image]

The odd thing I notice is that although I miss approximately a 40% of transactions sent, this won't happen if instead of the **bootstrap-node.sh**, I use the **solana-test-validator** without any extra arguments, where the transactions are all successfully executed even if use a way bigger tps rate.

The command I execute is the following:

```
./multinode-demo/bootstrap-validator.sh \
                        --enable-rpc-transaction-history \
                        --enable-cpi-and-log-storage \
                        --gossip-host $1 \
                        --allow-private-addr \
                        --log $LOGS/validator.log &
```

Both `$LOGS` and `$1` are guaranteed to be there and correct.

Since I use the same machine for both nodes, I cannot figure out how the node behaves differently in each run. I guess I miss something in my node configuration but cannot tell what it is.

I am using solana version 1.10.24

Also, I notice that when running the benchmark with **solana-test-validator**, the resources spent are low, despite the fact that all the transactions are executed:

[image]

On the contrary, the benchmark with **bootstrap-validator.sh** consumes way more resources while also dropping a handful of transactions, which is weird:

[image]

This is why I believe it has something to do with the node configuration.

*Edit*: Following I present the code with which I send each request. This code is executed 10000 times.

```
// The transaction RPC configuration
let RPC_SEND_CONFIG: RpcSendTransactionConfig = RpcSendTransactionConfig {
        skip_preflight: true,
        preflight_commitment: Some(CommitmentLevel::Confirmed),
        encoding: None,
        max_retries: None,
        min_context_slot: None
    };

// Create random triplet to use as instruction data to have different signatures
let random_data = Self::get_random_u8_triple();

// Serialize instruction
let instruction = Instruction::new_with_borsh(driver.program, &random_data, vec![]);

// Get recent blockhash
let recent_blockhash = driver.connection.get_latest_blockhash().unwrap();

// Create and sign  the transaction
let read_tx = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(
    &[instruction],
    Some(&driver.fee_payer.pubkey()),
    &[&driver.fee_payer],
    recent_blockhash,
);

let sig = driver.connection.send_transaction_with_config(&read_tx, RPC_SEND_CONFIG).unwrap()
```

The driver struct contains the RPC connection object to communicate with the node. This is created as follows:

```
// url is the node's endpoint
let connection = RpcClient::new_with_commitment(url, CommitmentConfig::confirmed());
```

*Disclaimer*: I know my server specs are way lower than the recommended, however this seems not to be the case here.

Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information on this topic.
Any help will be appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: please supply the client code used to send the transactions

Comment: @trent.sol I added the Rust code above. However, I am positive that the code is correct since it works with the solana-test-validator.

Comment: First, solana-test-validator isn't a real full fledged validator but a stubbed out validator to allow developers to test on a lightweight setup so resource usage comparison isn't very relevant.
I think modifying your example to use the memo program would allow people to attempt to reproduce with less code/complexity

Comment: @Arowana I can understand what you tell me for the solana-test-validator and it makes sense why it uses less resources. However, this makes me wonder how it is possible for the solana-test-validator to successfully execute all the transactions since as you say is not a full validator. I guess I should somehow modify the configurations of my actual validator, however I cannot find any sources on how to do so. Do you think it is acceptable to check the pending transaction blockhashes and manually retry them when it expires? I will check the memo program since I have never used it before. Thanks!

Comment: @trent.sol I think I figured out the problem, could you have a look on my answer and provide any comments? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After some searching, I think I noticed what went wrong in my case.

The problem was that the `bootstrap-validator.sh` script did not run the cli command `solana-validator`. Instead, it ran a `cargo  run   --bin solana-validator  -- <ARGS>` command which seems to retry incoming transactions when throughput is increased. I managed to solve my problem by replacing the `$program` variable in `bootstrap-validator.sh` with `solana-validator`.

Also, I noticed that when running the `cargo` command, all of my cores reach a 100% even when idle, while the `solana-validator` uses far less resources.

Could anyone explain why the `cargo run` command creates this issue?

Comment: `cargo run ...` just builds the bin from source and executes that instead of searching for it in `PATH`.  if you're observing a difference in behavior then it is between whatever version of the code base that you have checked out and whatever version of the solana cli tools you have installed

Comment: actually I am running same versions for both source and cli tools

Comment: assuming you got your cli tools from the labs binary release repository (which are release mode bins), is `cargo run ...` passing `--release`?  it will run a debug build by default